# how to limit the pre-loading of files in Java (JFileChooser)

Tags: java, excel, sas, preload

I have a Java program to search and load Excel files from the PC to use it in a SAS proyect. Usually works well but when I install it in a server with thousands of folders it takes too long and I would like to do it in seconds, not in 15 minutes.

I think is because `JFileChooser` try to load all directories and disk (the server has many disks). So I'd like to limit the search to the disk in witch I work. My programme is such that:

```
private String createProyect() {
   JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
   FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(NEW_PROYECT, EXTENSION_XLS, EXTENSION_XLSX);
   fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
   ...}
```

Maybe I need to use a configuration file but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [FileSystemView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) ?

If you use it, you will be able to modify the scope of your JFileChooser, like this example shows: [Example](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/)